# Mysql Compare 2 tables

Tags: mysql

How can I compare three values in different tables?

```
    pm_meta
    +----+----------+--------+----------+
    | id | item_id  |meta_key|meta_value|
    +----+----------+--------+----------+
    |  2 |     100  | google |googl.com |
    |  3 |     101  | yahoo  |yahoo.com |
    |  3 |     102  | msn    |msn.com   |
    +----+----------+--------+----------+

    pm_embed_code
    +------+-----------+------------+
    | id   | uniq_id   |embed_code  |
    +------+-----------+------------+
    |  100 |     abcd  |<iframe src=|
    |  101 |     dddc  |<iframe src=|
    |  102 |     ffdd  |<iframe src=|
    +----+----------+------------+



    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM pm_embed_code, pm_meta
            WHERE pm_embed_code.uniq_id = 'abcd'
            AND pm_embed_code.id = pm_meta.item_id
            AND pm_meta.meta_key = 'google' ";

    echo $row['meta_value']; // I want result "googl.com"
```

I want to check where `pm_embed_code.uniq_id= abcd` and select `pm_embed_code.id` then check where `pm_embed_code.id = pm_meta.item_id` and also if `pm_meta.meta_key = google` and if all print `meta_value`

UPDATE:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM pm_meta
            WHERE pm_meta.meta_key = 'google' ";

echo $row['meta_value'];
```

This one also not showing any... why?

Comment: I'm surprised that the pm_meta.ids are not unique, and the item_ids are !?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query:

select pmc.id as "pm_embed_code.id", pm.meta_key AS "pm_meta.meta_key" FROM pm_meta pm LEFT OUTER JOIN pm_embed_code pmc ON pmc.id = pm.item_id WHERE pmc.uniq_id = "abcd" AND pm.meta_key = 'google'

Code

$sql = "SELECT pmc.id as "pm_embed_code.id", pm.meta_key AS "pm_meta.meta_key" FROM pm_meta pm LEFT OUTER JOIN pm_embed_code pmc ON pmc.id = pm.item_id WHERE pmc.uniq_id = "abcd" AND pm.meta_key = 'google';"

echo $row["pm_meta.meta_key"];

Answer (score 0):

Use join:

```
Select * from  pm_embed_code join pm_meta on pm_emped_code.id=m_meta.item_id
where pm_embed_code.uniq_id = 'abcd' AND  pm_meta.meta_key = 'google'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        SELECT pm_embed_code.* , pm_meta.*
        FROM pm_embed_code
        INNER JOIN pm_meta
        ON pm_embed_code.id = pm_meta.item_id
          AND pm_meta.meta_key = 'google' 
        WHERE pm_embed_code.uniq_id = 'abcd'
```

Answer (score 0):

What error message you are getting. The query looks correct.

```
$sql = "SELECT pm.meta_value 
        FROM pm_embed_code pec, pm_meta pm
        WHERE pec.id = pm.item_id
        AND pec.uniq_id = 'abcd'
        AND pm.meta_key = 'google' ";

echo $row['meta_value'];
```

Comment: Empty result, if enable mysql error i got result "1"